# How to serialize proto3 message to a string and back?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

In Java, I want to convert a proto3 message into a string that:

1. I can send over HTTP
2. As more fields get added to the proto, it's still able to deserialize old strings?

If you are wondering why I need to serialize into a string, I have a proto:

```
message Order {
  ...
}
```

and I want to create a string 'order_tag' out of it that I want to pass around.

I saw [com.google.protobuf.TextFormat](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat) but it says it's for proto2 and also it doesn't say anything about backward compatibility.

Comment: Usually, the best option is to use the binaty serialize option, and if you need to send it over a text transport; base-64 encode the binary

Comment: @MarcGravell Sounds good to me, can you convert it into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can serialize the message to bytes, and use base64 encoding to convert the serialized value to string. In this way even if the fields change, you should be able to deserialize the string as long as the schema change happens within the restrictions defined in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#updating.

Don't use text encoding except for debugging purposes. It doesn't provide the same backward compatibility guarantee that the binary format provides (e.g. changing a field name will break existing serialized data).

To serialize to string:

```
BaseEncoding.base64().encode(order.toByteArray())
```

and to deserialize:

```
Order.parseFrom(BaseEncoding.base64().decode(orderStr))
```